# How to launch grails application in DNS?

Tags: grails, groovy, dns

I'm new to grails, I have created grails application that's running through "www.example.com:8080/appname" but I have to run the application in "www.example.com". How can I achieve this? and How to publish in Tomcat with my own server?

I have tried changing code in config.groovy

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        grails.serverURL = "http://www.example.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Usually you deploy your WAR file on a servlet container that is listening on that domain and port. However if you want to change the default HTTP port in Grails you can use `-Dserver.port=80` (see http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/run-app.html)

Comment: Could you please at least define your current setup a little more?  Is there already a tomcat on port 80 running or something forwarding to you app(-server)?  Where does "DNS" come into play here?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Apache web server to listen on "www.example.com" and forward request to your tomcat using AJP protocol.